# How to change the application switcher on Ubuntu 18.04 and 17.10?

Tags: unity, 17.10, 18.04, gnome-shell, application-switcher

Recently, Ubuntu change the UI back to GNOME.

Back on 16.04, when the UI was Unity, in order to change the application switcher, I just needed to install Compiz Config System Manager (ccsm), select another application switcher and disable the keyboard switching for Unity (in ccsm as well).

In 17.10 and 18.04, where [GNOME is used instead of Unity](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/latest-ubuntu-17-10-update-ditches-unity-desktop-installs-gnome), I can enable a different application switcher on ccsm but GNOME's application switcher still kicks in and don't see an option to disable it.

Any idea how to replace the application switcher on Ubuntu versions 17.10 and 18.04?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. What do you want to change specifically about the application switcher? GNOME Shell allows most of the things that Compiz did via dedicated extensions and themes.

Comment: Just want to know how to replace the application switcher, with a hope that there are several alternatives.

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/973/switcher/ may offer what you seek

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Ubuntu 17.10 and Ubuntu 18.04 with the Gnome Shell desktop, which uses mutter rather than compiz for managing windows, you can use different application switchers by installing appropriate extensions. [Alternatetab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/15/alternatetab/) is an officially supported extension that provides you with a document based switcher, rather than the default application based switcher. [Coverflow Alt-Tab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/97/coverflow-alt-tab/) allows switching windows in a cover-flow manner. These extensions can be installed from [Gnome extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/).